# An inequality involving expectation

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities

Let $f,g$ be two pdfs, and suppose $X$ is a random variable that has pdf $f$. Is it necessarily true that $E[f(X)] \ge E[g(X)]$?

Although I doubt this will help, but I got this problem from studying the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), which is defined as $D(f,g) = E\left[\ln (f(X)/g(X))\right]$ (with $X$ having pdf $f$ like above). It can be shown using Jensen's inequality that $D(f,g) \ge 0$, which is equivalent to saying that $E[\ln(f(X))] \ge E[\ln(g(X))]$. But my question removes the $\ln$ and I am wondering whether it will still be true.

In fact, I hypothesize that not only is it true for the $\ln$ function, but it will be true for any function that is increasing (which includes the identity function, which is my question here). So as a bonus, maybe we could ask if $E[h(f(X))] \ge E[h(g(X))]$ where $h$ is any strictly increasing function on positive reals. It seems like a continuous form of the [rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) to me.

Comment: Hint: Start with a Bernoulli random variable with probability of success $p$. Now compare against a Bernouilli with mass of 1 on 1. What do you notice as you vary $p$? Conclusion?

Comment: Hint: What other functions than $\text{ln}$ have the same characteristics as $\text{ln}$ w.r.t. Jensen's inequality?  Are any of them relevant to removing $\text{ln}$ from $\text{E}\dots$?

Comment: A related inequality that *is* true multiplies the right hand side by $E_f[g(X)] / E_g[g(X)].$  This might help you construct counterexamples.